# correct dns record ofr alt-svc h3/quic

Tags: https, dns, cloudflare, quic, alt-svc

We have just rolled out nginx 1.15.3 with quic/http3 support.

This is all working fine and we have nginx issuing the correct alt-svc header for quic.

My understanding is that you can further speed up the initial connection by providing a DNS record that tells the browser to use quic rather than starting with a TCP connection and then upgrading to quic.

I've been reading the cloudflare blogs (we use cloudflare DNS)  but it seems old and I get the impression there are a couple of alternate methods.
So I'm looking for guidance on the correct/best DNS entry.

This is the blog entry I've seen:
https://blog.cloudflare.com/speeding-up-https-and-http-3-negotiation-with-dns/

I've created the following record:

```
beta.onepub.dev 3600 IN HTTPS 1 . alpn=”h3,h2” ipv4hint=”x.x.x.x”
```

but I'm not even certain how to test it as the site is behind a cloudflare proxy.

I can see that cloudflare is issuing its own https record but I want to ensure that cloudflares connection to our site is also optimal to minimize latency when a user first connects to our site.

Am I doing the right thing?